# Angular select (change) method not working when plugin (niceselect) applied to it

Tags: css, angular, select, dropdown, onchange

Hi Hope everyone is doing fine unlike me as I am stuck in this problem since quite a while and seek your answer on this.  I am using angular version 9

I have a an HTML like:

```
<div class="view-product d-flex align-items-center">
  <p>View</p>                       
    <select  (change)="check()">
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="15">15</option>
       <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

and in Component.ts I have code

```
check(){
    console.log(1)    
  }
```

when my page gets loaded it forms 2 select *(one is hidden and other with the styles applied to it)*.
So when I choose any option "**check**" doesnot gets called. If I inspect the 'select' and remove its ***'display:none'*** in dev tools and then select an option '**check**' gets triggered.

So point is after the css or styles gets applied to it *change* doesnot work. Please Help me out !!

[image]

This is happening because of a js plugin file(niceselect plugin) which is beautifying the select control. If I exclude that js file the control becomes NORMAL AND FUNCTIONAL

I am including that file in my HTML Like

```
<html>
<body> 
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
  
  <!-- Plugins js -->
 <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: can u create https://stackblitz.com/ to replicate it ?

Comment: well it will be better if you can create a stackblitz. I am not able to understand your logic behind showing and hiding the select

Comment: With the existing code its not possible for 2 select elements to get created... there must be additonal code.. please explain the whole context..

Comment: How do you select an option if your select has "display: none" property?

Comment: @obaid - i am not creating 2 select but the css, one is hidden, other one with style implented is visible.

Comment: @maro- by using chrome developer tools and removing display:none style

Comment: I have added the image of 2 selects forming up. may be that helps